# Show that the set in the ring of polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$ is an ideal of $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, proof-writing, ideals

In the ring of polynomials with rational coefficients $\mathbb Q[x]$, let

$$I = \{h(x) \in \mathbb Q[x] : (x^2 - 2)  \ \text{  divides  }\ \  h(x)\}$$

Show $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb Q[x]$.

I know I must show that the set is an additive subgroup and that if $s\in I$ and $r\in R$ then $rs$and $sr \in  I$, but I am getting confused with the divider property in the first steps. Any help with this proof would help.

Also, how would I be able to show if this was a maximal ideal?

Thank you.

Comment: With $R$ you mean $\mathbb Q [x]$, right?

Comment: yes sorry, that is what i meant

Comment: If $R$ is a commutative ring, and $r$ is an element in $R$, then the set $I = \{ h \in R | r \text{ divides } h\}$ is an ideal. This is esential the set of multiples of $r$. Now if $k$ is a multiple of $r$, then so is $sk$ for any $s \in R$

Comment: Once you walk through the proof that $I$ is indeed an ideal, I'm guessing you won't have much trouble finding a proper ideal of $\Bbb Q[x]$ that properly contains $I$.  As for how to walk through the proof that $I$ is an ideal, note that any element of $I$ has the form $(x^2-2)f(x)$ for some $f \in \Bbb Q[x]$.  Use that observation to test the conditions you need to prove.

Comment: Rick why did you delete your answer??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The condition that $x^2 - 2$ divides a polynomial $h(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ means that there exists $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $h(x) = (x^2 - 2)g(x)$, *i.e.* $x^2 - 2$ is a *factor* of $h(x)$. Now if you have two polynomials $h_1(x)$ and $h_2(x)$ in $I$, then $(x^2 -2 )$ is a factor of both, a *common* factor. So we can write $h_1(x) + h_2(x) = (x^2 - 2)f(x)$ for some $f(x)$ and you can see the sum is in $I$. The other conditions you need to check follow similarly.

To see that $I$ is maximal, you just need to show that $x^2 - 2$ is irreducible (see why?). This follows from Eisenstein's criterion.

*Edit:* To go from irreducible polynomial to maximal ideal, you can proceed as follows: Suppose $J\subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is an ideal that properly contains $I$, so $I \subsetneq J$, and let $f \in J \setminus I$. Then $x^2 - 2$ doesn't divide $f$ (since $f \not\in I$) so their GCD is 1. By the Euclidean algorithm, you can find polynomials $s$ and $t$ such that $1 = f\cdot s + (x^2 - 2)\cdot t$. From here (check!) you get that $1 \in J$, hence $J = \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Thus the only ideal properly containing $I$ is the whole ring, so $I$ is maximal.

Comment: I still do not really understand how you show that I is maximal?

Comment: Added clarification in edit.